# Kotlin Tab Layout not shown

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, tabview

I´m building my first android project and I tried to implement a tabview with "upcoming" and "past" trips and i can´t make it to display anything inside the tabview, the tabview itself works just fine

Here the activity:

```
package com.example.tripwise

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.tripwise.Adapter.MyAdapter
import com.example.tripwise.ApplyToAll.BaseActivity

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout


class LandingPageActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        setupNavigationDrawer(toolbar)

        val newTripButtonView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.newTripButton)

        newTripButtonView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, NewTripActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Upcoming"))
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Past"))
        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

        val upcomingTrips: List<Trip> = emptyList() // Retrieve upcoming trips from your data source
        val pastTrips: List<Trip> = emptyList() // Retrieve past trips from your data source

        val adapter = MyAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tabLayout.tabCount, upcomingTrips, pastTrips)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab!!.position
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Here the adapter:

```
package com.example.tripwise.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import com.example.tripwise.Fragments.Past
import com.example.tripwise.Fragments.Upcoming
import com.example.tripwise.Trip

internal class MyAdapter(var context: Context, fm: FragmentManager, var totalTabs: Int, private val upcomingTrips: List<Trip>,
                         private val pastTrips: List<Trip>): FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> Upcoming.newInstance(upcomingTrips)

            1 -> Past.newInstance(pastTrips)
            else -> getItem(position)
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }
}
```

Here the past fragment:

```
package com.example.tripwise.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.tripwise.R
import com.example.tripwise.Trip


class Past : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var pastTrips: List<Trip>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pastTrips = arguments?.getSerializable("pastTrips") as? List<Trip> ?: emptyList()
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_past, container, false)

        val textViewHello = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewHello)
        textViewHello.text = "Hello"

        return rootView
    }

        companion object {
            fun newInstance(pastTrips: List<Trip>): Past {
                val fragment = Past()
                val args = Bundle()
                args.putSerializable("pastTrips", ArrayList(pastTrips))
                fragment.arguments = args
                return fragment
            }
        }
}
```

Here the past xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Past">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Past"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I´d really appreciate it, if anybody could tell me why for example the hello textview won´t be displayed